# can I replace a 2n2222 transistor with a tip31c

Tags: transistors

I have a TIP31c transistor, I need a 2N2222 for an [Arduino project](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-13-dc-motors/overview) to drive small dc motors with PWM, I found both transistors are NPN, but I don't want to hurt my Arduino, is the swap possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you get the pinning correct. The TIP31C is generally going to be lower current gain than the 2N2222 so it will require a higher base current for a given load.

If your small motor load is a low current device truly compatible with the ratings of the 2N2222 then I see no reason that would keep you from trying the TIP31C.